# Is an PIL image object mutable?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, mutable

I tried to run a function that looks like:

```
#file A_FILE
from PIL import Image

def apply_black_gradient(input_img, output_img, gradient):
    # parameters:
    # input_img : Image object
    # output_img: Image object
    # gradient: gradient rate applied to input_img

    ...Some codes here...
    output_img = Image.alpha_composite(input_im, gradient_im)

    return
```

My questions is when I used the function in another file

```
from A_FILE import apply_black_gradient

apply_black_gradient(img1,img2,gradient)

img2.show()
```

The result did not deem to be changed after applying the gradient.

I wonder why an instance in `Image` class of `PIL` is not mutable ?

I am sure the algorithm works because when I use 
    return output_img
I got the right result. I just want to pass the result to the argument.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be possible to _modify_ the `input_img` in-place, so in that sense they're "mutable" like a `list` or `dict` is. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54426778/355230).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding with Python, not PIL. In `apply_black_gradient` you assign a value to `output_img`. This only changes the value stored in that variable inside the function. So inside `apply_black_gradient`, the value of `output_img` has changed, but this has *not* changed the value of `img2` in your other file. The best thing to do in this situation is to `return output_img` as you say.

If you pass something like a list/dict/object as an argument, you can modify *parts* of it (elements of a list, members of a dict) inside the function, and see those modifications in the calling code. But there's no need to do that in the code you posted above, just use `return`.