# How to create overlapping semitransparent shapes on semitransparent background with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create image with semitransparent shapes drawn on transparent background. For some reason instead of staying transparent, the shapes are completely covering those beneath them. My code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256), (255,0,0,127))
drawing = ImageDraw.Draw(img, "RGBA")
drawing.ellipse((127-79, 127 - 63, 127 + 47, 127 + 63), fill=(0, 255, 0, 63), outline=(0, 255, 0, 255))
drawing.ellipse((127-47, 127 - 63, 127 + 79, 127 + 63), fill=(0, 0, 255, 63), outline=(0, 0, 255, 255))
img.save("foo.png", "png")
```

I would expect the result to look something like (except for background not being transparent):
[image: expected]
but it looks like:
[image: actual]

When I try to save it as GIF with `img.save("foo.gif", "gif")`, result is even worse. Circles are solid, no difference between outline and fill.

Comment: `ImageDraw.Draw` doesn't do blending, it replaces pixels with new ones. Doing what you want requires two steps—drawing with opacity on a blank canvas then compositing the result. There's an [example in the documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text) of drawing partially opaque text. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620169/355230) to a related question has another example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, `ImageDraw.Draw` doesn't do blending—whatever is drawn replaces whatever pixels that were there previously. To get the effect you want requires drawing things in a two-step process. The ellipse must first be drawn on a blank transparent background, and then that must be [alpha-composited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing) with current image (`bg_img`) to preserve transparency.

In the code below this has been implementing in re-usable function:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def draw_transp_ellipse(img, xy, **kwargs):
    """ Draws an ellipse inside the given bounding box onto given image.
        Supports transparent colors
    """
    transp = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0,0,0,0))  # Temp drawing image.
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(transp, "RGBA")
    draw.ellipse(xy, **kwargs)
    # Alpha composite two images together and replace first with result.
    img.paste(Image.alpha_composite(img, transp))


bg_img = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 256), (255, 0, 0, 127))  # Semitransparent background.

draw_transp_ellipse(bg_img, (127-79, 127-63, 127+47, 127+63),
                    fill=(0, 255, 0, 63), outline=(0, 255, 0, 255))
draw_transp_ellipse(bg_img, (127-47, 127-63, 127+79, 127+63),
                    fill=(0, 0, 255, 63), outline=(0, 0, 255, 255))

bg_img.save("foo.png")
```

This is the image it created viewed in my image file editor app which renders semi-transparent portions of images with a checker-board pattern. As you can see the opaque outlines are the only part that isn't.

[image: screenshot of image in image editor]

Comment: Great, this works. I'll wait for other answers for a while though, because I suspect there should be some easier way. `ImageDraw.Draw` can do blending when using `Image.new('RGB',...`.

Comment: Alex: Sure, no problem. I understand your suspicion, but don't think that's the case—but would be pleasantly surprise to find out there's a better way myself. This approach seems like a real [kludge](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/kludge) in my opinion, and is rather inefficient. As you may have noticed, `ImageDraw` only has primitive drawing capabilities and can't even draw anti-aliased lines or ellipses.

Comment: @martineau Thanks a lot ! after trying many stuff, including `blend`, finally this works !

Answer (score 0):

All 4th dimensions-transparency must be half. Also maybe problem is with drawing. Make mask for each ellipse and then sum up images. Last option- check pil function for bending images. That will propably be most certain and easiest solution.

The function for blending is:

```
PIL.Image. blend (im1, im2, alpha)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I just tried it and the result is not substantially different.