# Create a new image out of multiple images in a list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to write a NFT generator that has multiple folders such as `head, eyes, background` that all contain images. My code takes a random image from each folder and puts the paths of these images in a list.

So I have a list called `image_items` that contains the path of all images to create a unique new image.

Every image has a transparent background and has to be put on top of the previous image. So I'll have a new image created and I need to paste the first image in the list on top of it, then paste the second image in the list on top of that and so on.

I've tried doing this with the following code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import PIL

image = Image.open(image_items[0]) # Takes size of first image in list (all sizes are the same)
height, width = image.size

new_image = PIL.Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=(height, width))

for i in image_items:
    new_image.paste(Image.open(i), (0,0))
    
new_image.save('test.png')
```

The only problem is that it isn't pasting the images on top of eachother. It looks like it's just saving the last image in the list as `test.png`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Basically [How to overlay images in Python](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-overlay-images-in-python) is what I need, but instead of putting two images on top of each other, I need to put all images in the `image_items` list on top of each other:

Comment: `Image.paste()` doesn't honor alpha, it just replaces some or all of the destination image with the one that's being pasted. As its [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html) says "See [alpha_composite()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.alpha_composite) if you want to combine images with respect to their alpha channels." Also see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280891/how-do-i-make-the-background-of-an-image-that-is-pasted-on-top-of-another-image/65281395#65281395) of mine to a related question.

Comment: Also see this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388686/trying-to-create-a-composite-image-with-random-coordinates-using-pil-and-savin/67390446#67390446) of mine.